# Even with `return_dtype` in `apply` I get "Could not determine output type" in Polars

Tags: python-polars

This works:

```
f = lambda t: {'x': 1, 'y': "abc"}
df = pl.DataFrame( {'c': [f(0)] } )
print(df)
>>>>
shape: (1, 1)
┌───────────┐
│ c         │
│ ---       │
│ struct[2] │
╞═══════════╡
│ {1,"abc"} │
└───────────┘

df.schema
>>>>
{'c': Struct([Field('x', Int64), Field('y', Utf8)])}
```

While using `apply` with same `f` and `schema` dies with:
RuntimeError: BindingsError: "Could not determine output type"

```py
(df.with_columns('c')
    .apply(f, return_dtype=
            Struct([Field('x', Int64), Field('y', Utf8)])))
```

Comment: It works with `.with_columns(pl.col('c').apply(` - [`DataFrame.apply`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.apply.html#polars.DataFrame.apply) is different, the Notes in the docs mention it cannot track names and `pl.Expr.apply` should be used instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are really two different apply methods that are relevant here. There's [`DataFrame.apply`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.apply.html#polars.DataFrame.apply) and there's [`Expr.apply`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.apply.html#polars.Expr.apply).

When you do:

```
df.with_columns('c')
```

The output of that is a DataFrame that includes `c`. The `with_columns` isn't doing anything except making sure `c` exists and throwing an error if it doesn't.

Therefore when you chain an apply to that you're invoking the `DataFrame.apply` method. That method is equivalent to doing a for loop on `df.rows` where the input to the function is a tuple of the values of each column one row at a time. It's expecting the output of the function to be a tuple so if your `f` was:

```
f1 = lambda t: ({'x': 1, 'y': "abc"},)
```

then doing `df.apply(f1)` would work.

On the other hand if you invoke the `Expr.apply` by doing

```
df.with_columns(pl.col('c').apply(f))
```

then that works too because the `Expr.apply` is equivalent to running a for loop on all the values of the column from which it was invoked.

Obligatory anti-apply rant: If you're using apply in polars then you're not getting any benefit from the library. At that point, you're just doing a python for-loop with all of the inherent slowness.